# Can we construct WKT2 from PROJ4String correctly?

Tags: gdal, r, proj, well-known-text

There is the new WKT2, with great features, but there is a lot of data saved in WKT/PROJ4String too. The docs I read say the PROJ4String doesn't have enough info for a complete reference for coordinates, so, what are the alternatives for formats that don't have an EPSG CRS code?

Let's pick this example:

PROJ4String (+crs for the new format):

```
+type=crs +proj=utm +zone=19 +south +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0
```

If I run this over R, I get a result, but I don't know if is right:

```
> st_crs("+type=crs +proj=utm +zone=19 +south +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0"
+ )
Coordinate Reference System:
  User input: +type=crs +proj=utm +zone=19 +south +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0 
  wkt:
BOUNDCRS[
    SOURCECRS[
        PROJCRS["unknown",
            BASEGEOGCRS["unknown",
                DATUM["World Geodetic System 1984",
                    ELLIPSOID["WGS 84",6378137,298.257223563,
                        LENGTHUNIT["metre",1]],
                    ID["EPSG",6326]],
                PRIMEM["Greenwich",0,
                    ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433],
                    ID["EPSG",8901]]],
            CONVERSION["UTM zone 19S",
                METHOD["Transverse Mercator",
                    ID["EPSG",9807]],
                PARAMETER["Latitude of natural origin",0,
                    ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433],
                    ID["EPSG",8801]],
                PARAMETER["Longitude of natural origin",-69,
                    ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433],
                    ID["EPSG",8802]],
                PARAMETER["Scale factor at natural origin",0.9996,
                    SCALEUNIT["unity",1],
                    ID["EPSG",8805]],
                PARAMETER["False easting",500000,
                    LENGTHUNIT["metre",1],
                    ID["EPSG",8806]],
                PARAMETER["False northing",10000000,
                    LENGTHUNIT["metre",1],
                    ID["EPSG",8807]],
                ID["EPSG",17019]],
            CS[Cartesian,2],
                AXIS["(E)",east,
                    ORDER[1],
                    LENGTHUNIT["metre",1,
                        ID["EPSG",9001]]],
                AXIS["(N)",north,
                    ORDER[2],
                    LENGTHUNIT["metre",1,
                        ID["EPSG",9001]]]]],
    TARGETCRS[
        GEOGCRS["WGS 84",
            DATUM["World Geodetic System 1984",
                ELLIPSOID["WGS 84",6378137,298.257223563,
                    LENGTHUNIT["metre",1]]],
            PRIMEM["Greenwich",0,
                ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433]],
            CS[ellipsoidal,2],
                AXIS["latitude",north,
                    ORDER[1],
                    ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433]],
                AXIS["longitude",east,
                    ORDER[2],
                    ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433]],
            ID["EPSG",4326]]],
    ABRIDGEDTRANSFORMATION["Transformation from unknown to WGS84",
        METHOD["Geocentric translations (geog2D domain)",
            ID["EPSG",9603]],
        PARAMETER["X-axis translation",0,
            ID["EPSG",8605]],
        PARAMETER["Y-axis translation",0,
            ID["EPSG",8606]],
        PARAMETER["Z-axis translation",0,
            ID["EPSG",8607]]]]
```

Don't have enough info to construct the WKT2 means at the same time, there can exist several coordinates system that matches for a single PROJ4String, the result above can be  just one of them, maybe I'm confused but I can't found a solution how convert PROJ4Strings to WKT2.

Please, the explanations about this let's keep it in the concept.
If there is an example or software solution, let's keep it under opensource like R/GDAL.

Answer (score 2):

I saved the WKT into a text file "wkt2.prj" and had a try with gdalsrsinfo https://gdal.org/programs/gdalsrsinfo.html

```
gdalsrsinfo wkt2.prj -o proj4

+proj=utm +zone=19 +south +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0,0,0,0,0 +units=m +no_defs
```

The roundtrip is perfect so the WKT2 version should be just as good as the original Proj string.

Comment: that means, this WKT2 will not be able to get the advantages of others WTK2?, one big advantage of WKT2 over PROJ4String, is to have less error in the transformations.

Comment: I do not quite understand what you mean. UTM Zone 19 S has nothing special and Proj string supports it completely so no need to be worried about the accuracy of transformation in this case.

Comment: That is the point, proj4string vs wkt2, one point is that in transformations wkt2 have better accuracy, and, even if gdal says in reverse is the same, I don't understand how and why we can do this, thinking in PROJ4String and WKT2 differences, how GDAL get this results? how can validate it?.

Comment: Please clarify "transformations wkt2 have better accuracy". If the transformation that is needed for converting data from one CRS into another is recognized from the Proj string it is the same transformation. Do you have a concrete example about a transformation that you are interested in? Perhaps from EPSG:32719 into some other CRS?

Comment: The conversion from PRoJ4String is the next one, first pick the coord, transform to WGS84, then transform to the new coords, in part, due to that there is more errors, so, one of the great things about WTK2 is that we can convert it directly. I'm not interested in convert a specific CRS, the one I wrote here is an example, as I wrote, lets please keep the discussion under the "concept", proj4string to wkt2, have a software solution is great, but this question is not about a a software solution, is about the WKT2 specifications and transformations, even from GDAL, still need an argument of why.

Comment: You are totally mixing two different things: How the Proj library worked up till version 4 compared with how it works since version 5, and encoding coordinate system parameters either as proj string vs. WKT2. Current Proj library versions do not use WGS84 as an interim system even is the source and target systems are expressed with proj strings.

Comment: mm, and how works that?, because, you can't convert any WKT2 to Proj4String correctly, and doing that..., is like no meaning to WKT2, the objetives was get a better way to represent coords..)?

Comment: Usually you can convert WKT2 into Proj strings so that the transformations take exactly same paths and results are identical. WKT2 does support some features that Proj strings does not. For the common parts one it fundamentally not better than the other.